# python 3 script cannot access a domain on the same host

Tags: python, ubuntu, https, python-requests, gunicorn

I have 2 python apps:

1. Backend server, processes requests. It works via FastAPI + gunicorn (as a python library). I run it like this: `gunicorn main:app -b MINE_IP:8000 -c gunicorn_config.py --worker-class unicorn.worker.UvicornWorker`
2. Some kind of application based on the first application. *(code below)*

```py
import requests

j = requests.get(url="https://www.google.com/")
print(j.status_code)

o = requests.get(url="https://you_domen.domen:8000/")
print(o.status_code)
```

If I run this script on my laptop, both requests will give the result 200, but when I bring my script to the server (where it lies in the next folder with the first application running), it will give 200 when requested to Google, and when requested to 1 application via HTTPS, it will give an error, allegedly there is no such address. Disabling the firewall and restarting the system did not help, I assume that for some reason gunicorn does not want to process requests coming from the same computer.

During my tests, I received the following errors.

1. (https) When I access the domain + port (the standard option that works with external requests)

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='you_domen.domen', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f72750366e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

2. (http) When I access the domain + port (the standard option that works with external requests)

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='you_domen.domen', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f0d00bc66e0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

3. (https) When I address by public IP+port

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response'))
```

4. (http) When I address by public IP+port

```
requests.exceptions.SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='you_ip', port=8000): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(CertificateError("hostname 'you_ip' doesn't match 'you_domen.domen'")))
```

The firewall is disabled, and I also rebooted the system, I installed all updates, Ubuntu OS 22.04, Python 3.10.6, gunicorn 21.2.0, it is also installed in the system as an apt package, but it is not configured, so it should not interfere with anything.

Comment: gunicorn works fine locally ... not sure what your trying to do but presumably that domain does not exist...

Comment: But I've done tests, the script on my laptop can access the api, but when I try to send a request on the server itself, I can't access it. 

Can the fact that my application works through screen and I create a separate screen for each application somehow affect this situation?

Comment: Where is the server you are deploying to? Where is this custom domain? Are you sure that your laptop is talking to the same DNS as the server you've deployed to?

Comment: If I address as http://mu_domen.domen without specifying the port, then I get a welcome message from Nginx, and https already outputs an error that no one responds to this combination of ip+port

Comment: @C.Nivs My domain is provided by hosting, it is given automatically when ordering a VPS

Comment: In the search engine, I found information that [Error 111] Connection refused means that at the time of connecting to the server, the port is not available, it could be that I first take the port with the request request, and then I can't use it to contact the server because it is already occupied by me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a result, the error was due to the following reasons:

1. I specified a public IP at startup, which means that the IP addresses in the `localhost` group *(such as `0.0.0.0` and `127.0.0.1`)* are not listened to.
2. I specified the wrong certificate. `cert.pem` was enough for the browser, but Ubuntu tried to verify the authenticity of the certificate. I replaced `cert.pem` in the settings with `fullchain.pem`.

At this stage, I am glad that I was able to solve the problem, but I am also very disappointed that I spent 2 days on it and had to reinstall the system. :(